# Move y-axis in ggplot - scale_y_continuous(position = "right") doesn't work anymore

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am trying to move the y-axis label and tick marks to the right, but I get this error:

> Error in scale_y_continuous(position = "right", limits = c(62, 69), breaks = c(61, :unused argument (position = "right")

Was something updated in this functionality that I am not aware of?

Any suggestions on how I can modify my script to move the whole y-axis to the right of the graph will be appreciated.

**Code**

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(weeks = c(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
             mean = c(64, 65, 66, 66, 66, 67),
             lowerCI = c(63.4, 64.9, 64.5, 63.8, 62.1, 66.8),
             upperCI = c(65.6, 65.1, 66.5, 67.2, 68.9, 67.2))

sp_ts <- ggplot(data = df,
            aes(x = weeks,
                y = mean))

sp_ts +
  geom_point(shape = 15,
         size = 4) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lowerCI,
                ymax = upperCI),
            width = 0.05,
            size = 0.5) +
  labs(title = "Scatterplot of means",
   x = "Weeks",
   y = "Means") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1, 4),
                 breaks = c(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)) +
 scale_y_continuous(position = "right",
                 limits = c(62, 69),
                 breaks = c(61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69)) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = -Inf, xmax = 2, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "light blue", alpha = 0.2) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 2, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: [Current documentation](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html) suggests that `position = "right"` should still work. Does the problem persist if you run this code in a clean R session without loading any other package?

Comment: Yes, it still persists unfortunately

Comment: Do you know of another way to move the axis?

Comment: code works fine for me (ggplot2 version 2.2.1.9000, R 3.4.4)

Comment: Works for me with same setup as Richard. Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hl4u.png

Comment: @SHW what version of ggplot2 are you using?

Comment: Hi all, thank you for veryfying. I am using version 2.1.0. I am guessing that must be the problem then...